# How to horizontally align underbraces in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, underbrace

Like in the question, how can I align underbraces in LaTeX?
For example, the code

```
\begin{align*}
{\underbrace{Y \cdot \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^t x_i}{D}}_{\text{abc} } }
+ {\underbrace{\sum_{j=t+1}^n K_j }_{\text{abc } } }
\end{align*}
```

unfortunately yields an output where the text under the corresponding equations doesn't align.

Comment: In short, you need to insert an instruction such as `\vphantom{\sum_j}` in the argument of the first `\underbrace` directive.

Comment: I've seen the contribution you mentioned; if I wrap it around \underbrace{\vphantom{ Y \cdot \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^t x_i}{D}}}, it doesn't show the first summand anymore (which is logical).

Comment: *Nowhere* did I say you should wrap `\vphantom{\sum_j}` *around* the first `\underbrace` statement. Instead, I recommended you place it *inside* the first `\underbrace` statement. I.e., you should write `\underbrace{Y \cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^t x_i}{D} \vphantom{\sum_j}}_{\text{abc} }`.